# Golang keeps crashing on running main.go with exception Exception 0xc0000005

Tags: go, go-gorm, golang-migrate

I am new to Golang and have developed a basic REST API using GIN and gorm. The API works fine and there are no errors in the code. The main.go file is below:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/controllers"
    "github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/models"

    // "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "net/http"
)

func GoDotEnvVariable(key string) string {

    // load .env file
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading .env file")
    }

    return os.Getenv(key)
}

// CORS Middleware
func CORS(c *gin.Context) {

    // First, we add the headers with need to enable CORS
    // Make sure to adjust these headers to your needs
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
    c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Second, we handle the OPTIONS problem
    if c.Request.Method != "OPTIONS" {

        c.Next()

    } else {

        // Everytime we receive an OPTIONS request,
        // we just return an HTTP 200 Status Code
        // Like this, Angular can now do the real
        // request using any other method than OPTIONS
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusOK)
    }
}

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()

    host := GoDotEnvVariable("host")
    port := GoDotEnvVariable("dbport")
    user := GoDotEnvVariable("user")
    dbname := GoDotEnvVariable("dbname")
    password := GoDotEnvVariable("password")
    sslmode := GoDotEnvVariable("sslmode")

    models.ConnectDataBase(host, port, user, dbname, password, sslmode)

    router.Use(CORS)

    router.GET("/todos", controllers.GetTodos)          //  Get all the todos
    router.POST("/todos", controllers.CreateTodo)       // Create a new todo
    router.GET("/todos/:id", controllers.GetTodo)       // Fetch a single todo using id
    router.PUT("/todos/:id", controllers.UpdateTodo)    // Update and existing todo id has to be passed
    router.DELETE("/todos/:id", controllers.DeleteTodo) // Delete a todo using the id

    router.GET("/catagory/:username", controllers.GetCatagories) //  Get the Different catagories

    router.Run()
}
```

But, occasionally it keeps crashing upon running after which it never works and I have to restart my machine to fix it then it works. It throws the following exception

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x7fff91b70fff 0x1a34e3f0000
PC=0x1a34e3f0000

runtime: unknown pc 0x1a34e3f0000
```

I have researched a lot online but could not find an answer to fix this problem. Is there any solution to fix this permanently rather than restarting the PC.

Full Exception:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x7fff91b72fff 0x16f74c80000
PC=0x16f74c80000

syscall.Syscall6(0x7fff91794c70, 0x4, 0xc0002545c0, 0x0, 0xc000485f18, 0xc000485e90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:201 +0xf2
syscall.GetAddrInfoW(0xc0002545c0, 0x0, 0xc000485f18, 0xc000485e90, 0xa, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1718 +0xe5
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:109 +0x259
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP.func2(0xc00046afa0, 0xc0003f7f80)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:146 +0x32
created by net.(*Resolver).lookupIP
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:145 +0x41b

goroutine 1 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0x9, 0x1538, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup.go:299 +0x685
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/ipsock.go:280 +0x4d4
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0x12b5910, 0x4, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0xe, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x49d
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00029f6e8, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/dial.go:403 +0x23c
github.com/lib/pq.defaultDialer.DialContext(...)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:112
github.com/lib/pq.dial(0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0x137ed00, 0xc0003f7e60, 0xc00045e240, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:361 +0x52f
github.com/lib/pq.(*Connector).open(0xc00046af60, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0xc0000c5340, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:297 +0x193
github.com/lib/pq.DialOpen(0x137ed00, 0xc0003f7e60, 0xc000444600, 0x5f, 0x30001, 0x400, 0x255554aaaa, 0x39)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:275 +0x99
github.com/lib/pq.Open(...)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:265
github.com/lib/pq.(*Driver).Open(0x16c3050, 0xc000444600, 0x5f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:48 +0xa5
database/sql.dsnConnector.Connect(...)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:707
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0xc000380ea0, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0xc00038d401, 0x167c770, 0x10, 0xa)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1294 +0x214
database/sql.(*DB).PingContext(0xc000380ea0, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000200e0, 0xc00038d490, 0x138d920)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:799 +0x9f
database/sql.(*DB).Ping(...)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:817
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.Open(0x12b9e13, 0x8, 0xc00029fdd8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5f, 0xc000450750, 0xc00029fe00)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:97 +0x28a
github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/models.ConnectDataBase(0xc000365370, 0x9, 0xc000365de0, 0x4, 0xc0003fc840, 0x8, 0xc0003fd2a0, 0xb, 0xc0003fdcf0, 0xc, ...)       
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/src/github.com/usman2661/Golang-CRUD-API/models/setup.go:18 +0x268
main.main()
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/src/github.com/usman2661/Golang-CRUD-API/main.go:64 +0x1e6

goroutine 18 [select]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc000380ea0, 0x1383980, 0xc00043eb80)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1126 +0xf5
created by database/sql.OpenDB
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:740 +0x132

goroutine 19 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x168f080, 0x1383980, 0xc00043ebc0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:151 +0x1b9
net.glob..func1(0x1383980, 0xc00043ebc0, 0xc00038d4a0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc0004509a0, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x79
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup.go:293 +0xc2
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x168f090, 0xc00041d6d0, 0xc0004509b0, 0xd, 0xc00043ec00)
        c:/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x35
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        c:/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2cc
rax     0x7fff8e09d84a
rbx     0x7fff8e09d848
rcx     0x77
rdi     0xffffffffffbadd11
rsi     0x0
rbp     0x16f4dec2f90
rsp     0x505affeaf0
r8      0x94b
r9      0x94b
r10     0x94b
r11     0x94b
r12     0x7fff91980000
r13     [gin] Building...
[gin] Build finished
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

<nil>
Connected to the Database!!!
[GIN-debug] GET    /todos                    --> github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/controllers.GetTodos (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /todos                    --> github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/controllers.CreateTodo (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /todos/:id                --> github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/controllers.GetTodo (4 handlers)

Usman Ali@DRAX-LAP-UA MINGW64 ~/go/src/github.com/usman2661/Golang-CRUD-API (master)
$ gin --appPort 8080 --all -i run main.go
[gin] Listening on port 3000
[gin] Building...
[gin] Build finished
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x7fff91b72fff 0x262e38e0000
PC=0x262e38e0000

syscall.Syscall6(0x7fff91794c70, 0x4, 0xc000444e20, 0x0, 0xc00048bf18, 0xc00048be90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:201 +0xf2
syscall.GetAddrInfoW(0xc000444e20, 0x0, 0xc00048bf18, 0xc00048be90, 0xa, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_windows.go:1718 +0xe5
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:109 +0x259
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP.func2(0xc00045dbe0, 0xc00041f260)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:146 +0x32
created by net.(*Resolver).lookupIP
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:145 +0x41b

goroutine 1 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0x9, 0x1538, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup.go:299 +0x685
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/ipsock.go:280 +0x4d4
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x168f080, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0x12b5910, 0x4, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0xe, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x49d
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00021f6e8, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/dial.go:403 +0x23c
github.com/lib/pq.defaultDialer.DialContext(...)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:112
github.com/lib/pq.dial(0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0x137ed00, 0xc00041f140, 0xc000425650, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:361 +0x52f
github.com/lib/pq.(*Connector).open(0xc00045dba0, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0xc0003122c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:297 +0x193
github.com/lib/pq.DialOpen(0x137ed00, 0xc00041f140, 0xc00042cae0, 0x5f, 0x30001, 0x262bcd6edb8, 0x255554aaaa, 0x39)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:275 +0x99
github.com/lib/pq.Open(...)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:265
github.com/lib/pq.(*Driver).Open(0x16c3050, 0xc00042cae0, 0x5f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.1/conn.go:48 +0xa5
database/sql.dsnConnector.Connect(...)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:707
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0xc00038b380, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0xc000395901, 0x167c770, 0x10, 0xa)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1294 +0x214
database/sql.(*DB).PingContext(0xc00038b380, 0x13839c0, 0xc0000a2078, 0xc000395940, 0x138d920)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:799 +0x9f
database/sql.(*DB).Ping(...)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:817
github.com/jinzhu/gorm.Open(0x12b9e13, 0x8, 0xc00021fdd8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5f, 0xc000454880, 0xc00021fe00)
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jinzhu/gorm@v1.9.16/main.go:97 +0x28a
github.com/usman2661/Todo-Crud-Go/models.ConnectDataBase(0xc0003774a0, 0x9, 0xc000377f10, 0x4, 0xc0003f0970, 0x8, 0xc0003f13d0, 0xb, 0xc0003f1e20, 0xc, ...)       
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/src/github.com/usman2661/Golang-CRUD-API/models/setup.go:18 +0x268
main.main()
        C:/Users/Usman Ali/go/src/github.com/usman2661/Golang-CRUD-API/main.go:64 +0x1e6

goroutine 20 [select]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc00038b380, 0x1383980, 0xc000415c80)
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1126 +0xf5
created by database/sql.OpenDB
        c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:740 +0x132

goroutine 21 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x168f080, 0x1383980, 0xc000415cc0, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup_windows.go:151 +0x1b9
net.glob..func1(0x1383980, 0xc000415cc0, 0xc000395950, 0x12b530e, 0x3, 0xc000454ad0, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        c:/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x79
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/net/lookup.go:293 +0xc2
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x168f090, 0xc000458640, 0xc000454ae0, 0xd, 0xc000415d00)
        c:/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x35
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        c:/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2cc
rax     0x7fff8e09d84a
rbx     0x7fff8e09d848
rcx     0x77
rdi     0xffffffffffbadd11
rsi     0x0
rbp     0x262bcb03f40
rsp     0xe0199fe670
r8      0x94b
r9      0x94b
r10     0x94b
r11     0x94b
r12     0x7fff91980000
r13     0x0
r14     0x7fff8e09d84a
r15     0xc000007a
rip     0x262e38e0000
rflags  0x10202
cs      0x33[gin] Building...
[gin] Build finished
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x7fff91b70fff 0x1c8e0110000
PC=0x1c8e0110000

runtime: unknown pc 0x1c8e0110000
stack: frame={sp:0x455b3ff0c0, fp:0x0} stack=[0x0,0x455b3ff920)
000000455b3fefc0:  000001c8dffd8dc0  000000455b3ff030
000000455b3fefd0:  0000000000000000  000000455b3ff0c8
000000455b3fefe0:  000001c8dffc7820  000000455b3ff020
000000455b3feff0:  0000000000000000  00007fff8e850108
000000455b3ff000:  0000000000000000  000001c8dffc4570
000000455b3ff010:  000000455b3ff158  00007fff8ef2a8a1
000000455b3ff020:  00007fff8ef2a89b  00007fff9199ba6f
000000455b3ff030:  00007fff919800d8  000001c8dfff1b60
000000455b3ff040:  0000000000000005  000000455b3ff090
000000455b3ff050:  00007fff8ef28cd0  00007fff919b1810
000000455b3ff060:  000001c8dffc4570  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff070:  000001c800050005  00007fff8ef2a89b
000000455b3ff080:  000000000000001b  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff090:  0000000000000000  00007fff919800d8
000000455b3ff0a0:  0000000000000000  00007fff8ecd0000
000000455b3ff0b0:  0000000000000001  00007fff9199c734
000000455b3ff0c0: <000001c800000001  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff0d0:  00007fff0000ebb0  000000455b3ff1c8
000000455b3ff0e0:  000001c8dffc78f0  000000455b3ff148
000000455b3ff0f0:  0000000000250024  00007fff8e86b816
000000455b3ff100:  000001c8dffd7f80  00007fff91acc500
000000455b3ff110:  000001c8dffc4570  00007fff91acea5c
000000455b3ff120:  000001c80000094c  00007fff8e84b2d8
000000455b3ff130:  00007fff8e849138  00007fff91acc528
000000455b3ff140:  00007fff91adec6a  00007fff8e840000
000000455b3ff150:  00007fff91ad0f8c  00007fff91a00d80
000000455b3ff160:  000000451c1dc789  000001c8dffd8e18
000000455b3ff170:  000000455b3ff4d0  00000000c0000135
000000455b3ff180:  0000000000000000  0000000000000040
000000455b3ff190:  0000000000000004  00007fff91ae52f0
000000455b3ff1a0:  0000000000000001  000000455b3ff300
000000455b3ff1b0:  000001c8dfff1b60  00007fff919ae2a8
runtime: unknown pc 0x1c8e0110000
stack: frame={sp:0x455b3ff0c0, fp:0x0} stack=[0x0,0x455b3ff920)
000000455b3fefc0:  000001c8dffd8dc0  000000455b3ff030
000000455b3fefd0:  0000000000000000  000000455b3ff0c8
000000455b3fefe0:  000001c8dffc7820  000000455b3ff020
000000455b3feff0:  0000000000000000  00007fff8e850108
000000455b3ff000:  0000000000000000  000001c8dffc4570
000000455b3ff010:  000000455b3ff158  00007fff8ef2a8a1
000000455b3ff020:  00007fff8ef2a89b  00007fff9199ba6f
000000455b3ff030:  00007fff919800d8  000001c8dfff1b60
000000455b3ff040:  0000000000000005  000000455b3ff090
000000455b3ff050:  00007fff8ef28cd0  00007fff919b1810
000000455b3ff060:  000001c8dffc4570  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff070:  000001c800050005  00007fff8ef2a89b
000000455b3ff080:  000000000000001b  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff090:  0000000000000000  00007fff919800d8
000000455b3ff0a0:  0000000000000000  00007fff8ecd0000
000000455b3ff0b0:  0000000000000001  00007fff9199c734
000000455b3ff0c0: <000001c800000001  0000000000000000
000000455b3ff0d0:  00007fff0000ebb0  000000455b3ff1c8
000000455b3ff0e0:  000001c8dffc78f0  000000455b3ff148
000000455b3ff0f0:  0000000000250024  00007fff8e86b816
000000455b3ff100:  000001c8dffd7f80  00007fff91acc500
000000455b3ff110:  000001c8dffc4570  00007fff91acea5c
000000455b3ff120:  000001c80000094c  00007fff8e84b2d8
000000455b3ff130:  00007fff8e849138  00007fff91acc528
000000455b3ff140:  00007fff91adec6a  00007fff8e840000
000000455b3ff150:  00007fff91ad0f8c  00007fff91a00d80
000000455b3ff160:  000000451c1dc789  000001c8dffd8e18
000000455b3ff170:  000000455b3ff4d0  00000000c0000135
000000455b3ff180:  0000000000000000  0000000000000040
000000455b3ff190:  0000000000000004  00007fff91ae52f0
000000455b3ff1a0:  0000000000000001  000000455b3ff300
000000455b3ff1b0:  000001c8dfff1b60  00007fff919ae2a8
rax     0x7fff8e84be7c
rbx     0x7fff8e84be7a
rcx     0x41
rdi     0xffffffffffbadd11
rsi     0x0
rbp     0x455b3ff300
rsp     0x455b3ff0c0
r8      0x0
r9      0x0
r10     0x0
r11     0x94b
r12     0x7fff91980000
r13     0x0
r14     0x7fff8e84be7c
r15     0xc000007a
rip     0x1c8e0110000
rflags  0x10202
cs      0x33
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
```

Comment: Can you copy the full stacktrace? if it is a panic, you will be able to identify the line where the error occured.

Comment: "I have to restart my machine to fix it" this is almost certainly a machine issue. A Go application retains nothing between executions; if an issue persists between executions, it's something outside the application, and if a reboot fixes it, it's likely OS-level.

Comment: @ShintoPhilip I have edited the question and added the full exception now.

Comment: Fist check for other issues in the go issues tracker. Since this is coming from `lookupIP`, you could see if setting `GODEBUG=netdns=go` avoids the problem.

Comment: Its an access violation.  I can't quite tell why yet.  It could be a bug in the go resolver libraries.  I've posted issues about the go resolver before.   Thought they were fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a goroutine deadlock.
In case of a deadlock, all the goroutines running in the program will exit and produce a stacktrace like the one you look at.

The program will be terminated by the go runtime. Even though your http server might have a recover function, recovery is not possible from deadlocks.

Comment: this happens very often with me while I run and have to restart the PC each time. Surely there should be a command or way to reset or fix the deadlock?